# Can Tableau data be passed into Salesforce?

Tags: account, data, tableau-crm, tableau

We are pulling data from multiple sources into Tableau and would like to leverage the salesforce and tableau integration to push data back info our Salesforce account records.  Is that possible?  And if not, has anyone used Mongo, Snowflake or something similar to write data back to Salesforce?

Comment: any data can be passed into salesforce if you have the developers willing to work on it.

Comment: Alternative -- Use the [Tableau Visualization LWC](https://www.tableau.com/products/viz-lightning-web-component-salesforce) and fetch as display-only